# Accessing JSON object with key from a string array using dot operator in JS not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

The JSON object I got was from another PHP file that is called through `$.ajax()`. For example, I returned from my PHP file a `echo json_encode(array('a' => 'b'))`.

Then, I have the following `$.ajax()` code:

```js
let objKey = ['a'];

$.ajax({
  type        : 'POST',
  url         : 'phpfilehere.php',
  dataType    : 'json',

  success     : function(obj) {
      alert(obj.objKey[0]);
  }
});
```

It should have alerted `b` instead of `undefined`. Then, I tried `alert(obj.a)` and it worked. It alerted `b`. How do I access the value of the JSON object with an array of string which all corresponds to the key of said JSON object?

Comment: Use `obj[objKey[0]]` instead, for more information [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Syntax)

Comment: Hm how will that fix it? Shouldn't it be the same as using the dot operator?

Comment: No it is not the same and yes it will fix it.

Comment: @HMR How is it different then? Could you please provide an answer below?

Comment: Btw., this has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Dot operator expects _**exact**_ property name after object and does **not evaluate** variables. So `obj.objKey` accesses property of `obj` named `objKey`.

Comment: @hindmost THAT is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you hindmost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.objKey[0]` is false in your case, it's good if your object is like :

```
obj = { 'objKey': ['b'] }
```

---

You have two solutions in your case

```
alert(obj[objKey[0]]);
```

or

```
alert(obj.a);
```

---

Reference

- [Property Accessors MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)